# "not a git repository" ao executar git add

Tags: git

Estou tentando executar `git add .` mas recebi o seguinte erro:

```
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories):
```

Como resolvê-lo?

Comment: Você precisa primeiramente dar inicio ao repositório com o comando ```git init```.

Comment: Você está fazendo o upoad de suas alterações para um repositório, correto? Como você pegou os fontes?

Answer (score 3):

O erro indica que não há repositório git no seu projeto.
Para resolver este problema basta roda o seguinte código:

```
> git init
```

A partir deste momento você pode realizar os commits do seu projeto com os seguintes comandos:

Atenção: Certifique-se que seu projeto tenha algum arquivo.

```
> git add .
> git commit -m "Mensagem de commit"
```

Os passos seguintes dependerão do seu objetivo, caso queira colocar seu projeto em um repositório online como o GitHub realize as seguintes configurações alterando os valores dentro da chave para o seu link do github e removendo as chaves:

```
> git branch -M main

> git remote add origin [URL DO REPOSITÓRIO AQUI]
```

O seguinte comando empurrara os arquivos para o repositório:

```
> git push -u origin main
```

Comment: Obrigado. Funcionou perfeitamente!